# MSMQ for CQRS -- Building Service Bus

Tags: msmq, cqrs, lokad-cqrs

How can i build by own service Bus? i know there are Plenty of open source service bus available like NService Bus,Rhino Bus etc... But i want to learn by doing it..

1)How will you build  the Bus? what the characteristics of it

2)How can i make it independent of the Queue technology.. ie it should work with MSMQ as azure queue(never worked with azure queue)

3)How Can i Implement Listener to to it? I got a link .. is it how Nservice Bus has done
[(MSMQListner)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/manoj/archive/2005/10/16/70979.aspx)

4) How can i activate the Queue .. can i host my service in IIS so that handling load will not be a problem (I hope so)

5)How will the Host option for MSMQ will be?

Please i dont want to use WCF .Just because it makes Messaging architecture as RPC calls

Comment: Why not read through the source for NServiceBus, Rhino Bus, Mass Transit etc?

Comment: I think good recommendation is to start with something simpler, like [Minibus](http://https://github.com/SteveBate/MiniBus), to have the clean and simple implementation.  As usual, dealing with integration scenarios, You will be implementing the infrastructure part by yourself, things such as serialization, handlers wrappers, replying, etc. You shouldn't start with framework, instead, the messaging **library** built on top of MSMQ is the best for learning. Then go with automatic retries, exception handling policies, and concurrency

Comment: This video goes through a lot of considerations for building your own service bus: https://particular.net/videos/so-you-want-to-build-a-service-bus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few lessons I've learned while building [Lokad.CQRS](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cqrs/) (service bus infrastructure for Windows Azure):

- Learn by reading sources of the other service buses and then picking the best ideas. Try to implement. After a few iterations you'll be getting the idea.
- Actual service bus code is simple. But it takes time to get it done right (I'm still far from it).
- It's easier to build service bus for a queue tech, than trying to make it decoupled from queue implementation
- Azure Queues are not close to MSMQ (no DTC, much smaller message size limit, cloud specifics)

Hope this helps,
Rinat